# Firebase Functions Request Body is Empty

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to make a POST request within a firebase function. Everything works fine when using Postman, but after integrating it into a cloud function, I'm getting the following error (code 400):

```
errors: {
 [
   0: "A non-empty request body is required."
 ]
}
```

Here's my code:

```
exports.getAccessToken = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    const postBody = JSON.stringify({
        'customerId': customerId,
        'userId': userId,
        'sdkKey': sdkKey,
    });

    const options = {
        hostname: 'api-uat.flinkey.de',
        path: '/v3/sdk/token',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'flinkey-API-Key': flinkeyAPIKey,
            'Authorization': authorizationToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    };

    const req = https.request(options, res => {
        let data = '';
        res.on('data', d => {
            data += d;
        });
        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', error => {
        console.error(error);
        response.status(500).send(error);
    });

    req.write(postBody);
    req.end();
});
```

Here's the link to the documentation: https://developers.flinkey.com/api/operations/app-sdk/

Comment: The docs example has a body with customerId/sdkkey/userid which your code seems to be missing...?

Comment: Do I have to put this into the options object?

Comment: Yes, see for example [here](https://reqbin.com/code/javascript/wzp2hxwh/javascript-post-request-example) how to make a POST request with a body.